# How to get the nearest and the smallest token before the known one?

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation

I have a string which looks like:

> "some token","another token","yet
>   another token","Necessary Token","KNOWN TOKEN","next to
>   known token"

How to get "Necessary Token" with regular expression from the given string?

I tried the next expression:

```
\"(.+)\","KNOWN TOKEN"
```

but it matches the whole substring from the beginning to the "KNOWN TOKEN" part. I need to make it 'lazy' but I cannot manage how to achieve this (I tried to put question marks after the first group and inside it and it didn't work).

Comment: You probably wanted 'non-greedy' and not 'lazy'. It is not lazy, it has to parse your whole text up to KNOWN TOKEN.

Comment: @eumiro: do not hesitate to make some editions if you know how it's called exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to "anything else than quotes":

```
\"([^\"]+)\","KNOWN TOKEN"
```

Your `(.+)` matches everything (quotes too) between your `some token...` until the `...Necessary Token`. My `([^\"]+)` may match only `Necessary Token`, so the previous quotes will be set to the initial quotes of `Necessary Token`.

Or, if your programming language allows it, use a good CSV-parser that will take care even of commas within quotes, find the KNOWN TOKEN and take the element before it.

Comment: the problem is that your first example returns "some token","another token","yet another token","Necessary Token"

Comment: the second does work, bingo! Could you explain why is it work?

Answer (score 3):

```
\"([^\"]+)\","KNOWN TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use:

```
.*\"(.+)\","KNOWN TOKEN"
```

[**Working link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/jhwoJui3U4)